# oracle incorrect primary key inserted in the table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am quite baffled by my current situation:

My ruby on rails application is generating the following query:

INSERT INTO "MEMBER_ROLES" ("ID", "NAME", "ORG_ID") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3)  [["id", 55], ["name", "test6"], ["org_id", "2"]]

The query seemed to have worked and I can see the above record in my database table except that the 'id' field is not set to '55' but '56'.

This happens with every insert. The actual primary key inserted is always 1 more than what the above insert statement looks like.

I am not sure if this has to do with the way my table is created?

```
CREATE TABLE member_roles 
(
  id  NUMBER(38,0) primary key,
  name VARCHAR2(200) not NULL,
  org_id VARCHAR2(200) not NULL,
  created_at DATE default sysdate not null,
  updated_at DATE default sysdate not null
)


CREATE SEQUENCE MEMBER_ROLES_SEQ;

set define off;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER member_roles_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON MEMBER_ROLES 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT MEMBER_ROLES_SEQ.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

Comment: The ID field is controlled by a SEQUENCE.  The ID passed in is altered before the insert statement ; obtaining the "Next value"  from the sequence.  `Select Sequence_owner, Increment_By, Last_Number from ALL_Sequences where sequence_name = 'MEMBER_ROLES_SEQ'` will show you the current sequence.  The .nextval adds 1...  Thus whatever ID you pass in is going to be "REPLACED" what whatever is in the sequence.nextval.  that's what `new.Id` is.  The ID passed in is replaced with the Sequence.nextval from the member_roles_Seq.  Simply put, the ID you pass in is IRRELEVANT.  It's overridden by SEQ.

Comment: Thanks XQbert. Is it possible to insert the id mentioned in the initial query. This is important because the above query is followed by another query(for a join table) which inserts the above primary key as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get the id you use for insert? Do you get it from a sequence?
The trigger overwrites your id with the next sequence value.

you can try to insert with id=-99 and you'll see it will be overwritten too...

Comment: use *RETURNING id INTO :out* to retrieve the correct id

Comment: Can I update the sequence or the trigger somehow so that id in the insert statement is inserted instead?

Comment: you can alter the trigger with `IF :new.id IS NULL THEN` before `SELECT...` and `END IF;` after it, but you risk a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT VIOLATED exception, when someone inserts a manual id and the sequence reaches this value

Comment: for test purposes you can disable the trigger

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Do you think in my scenario do we need the trigger at all?

Comment: Using seq.nextval is a way to guarantee unique values when race conditions could otherwise occur.  I'm not sure how you're getting your ID's you're inserting with; but Duplication could occur in most other methods.  This trigger method using sequence is, IMO, the safest way to assign a unique ID.  If you're going to make a change, be certain you understand why this was done this way originally; and ensure you're generation of an ID will not falter under load.

Comment: My personal opinion is you shouldn't know the id before INSERT, you should retrieve the id and all other column values after insert (e.g. using *INSERT INTO ... RETURNING INTO* construct). The same situation is on UPDATE, you should always retrieve the column values after UPDATE. In your scenario there is important, whether the DB is used by someone else, who mades inserts, maybe he is relying on the trigger... If your persistence layer provides ID for the INSERT, ensure it uses the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a new question about behavior of rails and why it is inserting that in the first place.